# How Can I Use botva2.dll on Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

How can I change the InnerNotebook on Inno Setup by glass image.png?
I know that I must use the dll botva2, but I don´t know the code.

This is my installer:
[image]

But I want to put this effect on all page:
[image]

Comment: Could you include a link to an official website of `botva2.dll`, please ?

Comment: As you already think you have to use `botva2.dll` can't you read the rest of the article or look up its documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 2 pictures:

1. background
2. transparent picture (.png) which is above background.

All components must be transparent (Labels or TNewStatictexts support this)

How to use botva2.dll and call it's functions is shown below.

a) Declare plug-in export:

> ```
> procedure GdiPlusShutdown; external 'gdipShutdown@{tmp}\botva2.dll stdcall delayload';
> ```

b) Add botva2.dll into your installer:

> ```
> [Files]
> Source: botva2.dll;       Flags: dontcopy;
> ```

c) Extract .dll into Temp directory (the best is to do this in some Init function like InitializeWizard();

> ExtractTemporaryFile('botva2.dll');

d) Call your function:

> ```
> procedure MyFunc();
> begin
> // Unload ComCtrls functions
>   GdiPlusShutdown; // Function from botva2.dll
> end;
> ```

If you need whole solution like this: [image: Graphical Installer]

I can recommend you my Inno Setup expansion called Graphical Installer: [Graphical Installer website](http://graphical-installer.com/).

Comment: Dear Slappy, thank you for your reply. But i don´t konw very well the script of Inno Setup. I am to learn to make script a few time. I insert the code that you show me but it give me a error on the "producer MyFunc ();. IF you can give me a script with a simple example, i will be greatful. Best regards.

Comment: @Slappy, you don't need to extract the imported library to a temporary folder. It's enough to use something like `...@files:botva2.dll` and the rest will InnoSetup do for you.

Comment: TLama is right, that is also possible. I posted only piece of code- you have to use your own procedure name which may dirrers to 'MyFunc()'.